# Cannot load ZipFileSet in Ant

Tags: javascript, java, xml, jenkins, ant

i get a typeerror when executing the below in my ant deploy.xml file, any idea what's wrong?
This worked about two weeks ago

**command**:ant -f deploy.xml

**ant version**: 1.9.4

**error**:*javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot load script from Packages.org.apache.tools.ant.types.ZipFileSet*

```
<script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
         var version = java.lang.System.getProperty("java.version");
         if ( version.startsWith("1.8.0")) {
             load(Packages.org.apache.tools.ant.types.ZipFileSet);
             load(Packages.org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Zip);
         } else {
             importClass(Packages.org.apache.tools.ant.types.ZipFileSet);
             importClass(Packages.org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Zip);
         }
         ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the suggestion below fixed the error.

i.e.

```js
var Zip = org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Zip;
```

[Java 8 Javascript Engine backwards compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503100/java-8-javascript-engine-backwards-compatibility)