# Generate url nocache parameter string by Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

To invalidate client (browser) caches for new releases, I have to add a random string parameter to my asset urls.

I develop a web application with Spring MVC and use Maven to build the project.

My question is how to generate such strings with Maven? It make sense when I have the possibility to place a variable in any file, JSP, tags like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/master.css?cache={random}" media="all"/>
```

And replace the variable with the random string while building.

Comment: The version number would be also ok. But how can I substitute it in any file by Maven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of generating a random String during the Maven build, you can just use the version number. This is different for every releases and will fit your use-case.

For this to work, you can use the [filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) capabilites of the `maven-war-plugin`. In your JSP, declare the placeholder `${project.version}`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/master.css?cache=${project.version}" media="all"/>
```

Then, during the Maven build, you can filter this file and Maven will automatically replace this placeholder with the current version.

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <webResources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </webResources>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

---

If you really want to generate a random String, you can use the [`maven-antrun-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) with the following task (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7717498/1743880)):

```xml
<scriptdef name="generateguid" language="javascript">
    <attribute name="property" />
    <![CDATA[
    importClass( java.util.UUID );

    project.setProperty( attributes.get( "property" ), UUID.randomUUID() );
    ]]>
</scriptdef>

<generateguid property="guid1" />
<echo message="${guid1}" />
```

The property `guid1` will then hold your random String, be sure to set [`exportAntProperties`](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html#exportAntProperties) to `true` in the plugin configuration. You can then apply the same logic as above (resource filtering) with the `${guid1}` placeholder instead of `${project.version}`

Comment: After declaring the plugin I got 08-Oct-2015 14:21:02.740 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
. Any idea?

Comment: @RobertMoszczynski That seems to be an error build the server startup. Was the property correctly replaced in the WAR file?

Comment: Yes, it was correctly replaced. The question is solved and the solution is very cool. Thank you! But maybe you have additionally a idea how tho solve the Tomcat problem.

Comment: @RobertMoszczynski I suggest you create another question with your POM and complete stacktrace.

Comment: I see that the replaced version is always 1.0-SNAPSHOT and I can't change it with <project...><version>2.8.7</version>...

Comment: I tried mvn dependency:purge-local-repository but it doesn't helped.

Comment: @RobertMoszczynski Are you saying that with a project having a version of 2.8.7 (i.e. the element "project > version" of the war is 2.8.7), the placeholder `${project.version}` gets replaced by 1.0-SNAPSHOT? This would be really weird.

Comment: Yes it is. There is a Maven inconsistency. No plan how to solve that. I will make a additional question for that.

Comment: Sorry, my script copied the war from a old 1.0-SNAPSHOT path. Yes, the variable is correctly replaced with 2.8.7. I create an another question special for the Tomcat exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) capability of the Maven resources plugin.

[Here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) is how you would specify the resource plugin configuration for web resources. The WAR plugin makes use of the resource plugin internally, so the configuration is identical and you can refer to the documentation for the resources plugin.

Comment: The `maven-resources-plugin` is not appropriate here since we're talking about a JSP here

Comment: Sure it is. How do you think files are copied from `src/main/webapp` to the `target` folder? The WAR plugin uses the resources plugin internally to copy files, so the configuration options are identical.

Comment: Let me rephrase, a JSP is not a main resources as per Maven terms, it is a webapp file so it should not be handled by this plugin. You're going to have to specify you filter src/main/webapp, which will add these files to the jar. In your edited answer, you link to `maven-WAR-plugin` documentation, not `maven-resources-plugin`.

Comment: Where are JSP files located? In `src/main/webapp`. This is just a standard resource provided by the WAR plugin, with the specific terminology of `webResources`. The configuration of `webResources` is identical to standalone resources, because they are implemented from the same Maven building blocks.

Comment: I'm removing my downvote, I initially thought you were suggesting to use `<build><resources>` element instead of the `webResources` element of maven-war-plugin (because that's what you link to)

Comment: Thanks. I really should have just included an example instead of only referring to a link. The initial link provides very good practical example of how to do filtering in Maven, but is missing essential context.

Answer (score -1):

As proposed by Tunaki, you can use the version number rather than a random number.
In both cases Maven Resources Plugin and its filter option will help you.

See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

**EDIT** : you can get version number with `${project.version}` property in Maven.

Comment: The `maven-resources-plugin` is not appropriate here since we're talking about a JSP here

Comment: Yes, indeed I was thinking about filtering option on Maven War Plugin but answered too quickly..